# How to get the SUM of a column in a relational database "Laravel5"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I hope somebody could help me with my problem. I’m stack with this little relational issue with Laravel 5.

Problem:

I want to get the SUM of my "amount" column in may "Wallet" model.

My current code that is working.

```
public function children()
{        
    return  $this->hasMany('App\Tree', 'parent_id','id')
                 ->with('children')
                 ->with('user')
                 ->with('user.wallets');
}
```

Note: This return with the following data.

```
[{
    ...,
    children: [...]
    user: {
        ...,
        wallets: [...] // return list of array
    }
}]
```

My solution but return no luck.

```
return  $this->hasMany('App\Tree', 'parent_id','id')
                     ->with('children')
                     ->with('user')
                     ->with('user.wallets', function($q) {
                        $q->sum('amount');
                     });
```

desired result

```
[{
    ...,
    children: [...]
    user: {
        ...,
        wallets: [
            ...,
            amount: XXX.XX // e.g The total sum of the column, could be any number based on the sum of the column.
        ]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: Hello @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, do you happen to know of any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified `withCount()`. Change your `user` and `children` relationships:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User')
        ->withCount(['wallets as wallets_amount' => function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('sum(amount)'));
        }]);
}

public function children()
{        
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tree', 'parent_id', 'id')
        ->with('children', 'user');
}
```

Then you can access the sum with `$user->wallets_amount`: